# Public datasets of signals

Tags: continuous-signals, data-request

Is there a public database where I can find or anyone can provide me real signals.

I'm looking specifically for pairs of natural signals (e.g. from Sensor networks) to test some cross-correlation and cross-spectrum methods.

Answer (score 3):

The IEEE used to host something called the Signal Processing Information Base, which is gone but there is a mirror at:

http://spib.linse.ufsc.br/database.html

There is also some links from Mike Porter's Ocean Acoustics Library at:

http://oalib.hlsresearch.com/